# Inventory Part's OnHand Quantity - NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

To get some kind of notifications on creation of Invoices in NetSuite if the OnHand Quantity is low, 0 or less than 0.

I thought this could be achieved within NetSuite by setting up email notifications / alerts to users if Inventory Part is outofstock i.e OnHand is 0 or less than 0.

Let me know if there is a way to do this using NetSuite Workflows with an email alert action.

Else, let me know if there is any other way to implement this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use Saved Search alerts.  You can set up a search that returns the results corresponding with what you want to be notified on, then go to the Email tab in the search and check the box for 'Send Email Alerts when records are Created/Updated'.  Then enter the desired recipient(s) and save.

Each time a record is created that matches the criteria specified in the search, the system will send an email to the recipients specified.